# Why is my code throwing 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'basic_investment_return'?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

Why is this line of code

```
withdraw.investment.basic_investment_return -= withdraw.basic_withdraw_amount
```

throwing this error

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'basic_investment_return'
```

**Views**

```
@login_required
def create_withdrawal_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        basic_withdraw_form = BasicWithdrawalForm(request.POST)
        if basic_withdraw_form.is_valid():
            withdraw = basic_withdraw_form.save()
            withdraw.investment.basic_investment_return -= withdraw.basic_withdraw_amount
            print(withdraw.investment.basic_investment_return)
            withdraw.save()
            messages.success(request, 'your withdrawal of {} is successfull '.format(withdraw.basic_withdraw_amount))
        else:
             messages.success(request, 'your withdrawal of {} is unsuccessfull '.format(withdraw.basic_withdraw_amount))
    else:

        basic_withdraw_form = BasicWithdrawalForm()
    context = {'basic_withdraw_form': basic_withdraw_form}
    return render(request, 'create-basic-withdrawal.html', context)
```

**models**

```
class Investment(models.Model):
    basic_investment_return = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
   

class Withdraw(models.Model):
    investment = models.ForeignKey(Investment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    basic_withdraw_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
```

**Forms**

```
class BasicInvestmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Investment
        fields = ['basic_deposit_amount']


class BasicWithdrawalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Withdraw
        fields = ['basic_withdraw_amount']
```

Comment: Can you add the payload the POST request here?

Comment: Your `BasicWithdrawalForm` has `fields = ['basic_withdraw_amount']`, i. e. `investment` is not a field on your form and you also don't set the value for that on your instance hence `withdraw.investment` has the value `None`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I understand but how can I call basic_investment_return from the investment model. I want to use it in the ```create_withdrawal_view```. I don't want to use investment as a field in ```BasicWithdrawalForm```.

Comment: @Metalgear I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain the data you uploaded for POST request here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are adding non model field `basic_deposit_amount` can't see that in model.

```
class BasicInvestmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Investment
        fields = ['basic_deposit_amount']
```

In my opinion you may have withdraw or investment value coming  as once try to print both value on console as this will certainly gives idea which value is coming as none.

```
@login_required
def create_withdrawal_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        basic_withdraw_form = BasicWithdrawalForm(request.POST)
        if basic_withdraw_form.is_valid():
            withdraw = basic_withdraw_form.save()
            if withdraw and withdraw.investment is not None:
                withdraw.investment.basic_investment_return -= withdraw.basic_withdraw_amount
                print(withdraw.investment.basic_investment_return)
                withdraw.save()
                messages.success(request, 'your withdrawal of {} is successfull '.format(withdraw.basic_withdraw_amount))
            else:
                #Raise certain exception saying basic_investment_return is none
        else:
             messages.success(request, 'your withdrawal of {} is unsuccessfull '.format(withdraw.basic_withdraw_amount))
    else:

        basic_withdraw_form = BasicWithdrawalForm()
    context = {'basic_withdraw_form': basic_withdraw_form}
    return render(request, 'create-basic-withdrawal.html', context)
```

Comment: investment is not define. ```if withdraw and investement is not None:```